# my application has stopped unexpectedly in android please try again

Tags: android

I have an error in my android code:

```
    case R.id.bSQLOpenView:
        Intent i = new Intent("com.fps.say.SQLView");
        startActivity(i);
        break;
```

and my logcat says there's no activity found to handle intent..
I already declared my class at AndroidManifest.xml why do i still get this error.

this is my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fps.say"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
                <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fps.say.MENU" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".SayActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fps.say.SAYACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".TextPlay"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fps.say.TEXTPLAY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Email"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fps.say.EMAIL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Camera"
            android:label="Camera Application" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fps.say.CAMERA" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".AboutUs"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fps.say.ABOUTUS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Prefs"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fps.say.PREFS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>        

        <activity
            android:name=".Data"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fps.say.DATA" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity
            android:name=".GFX"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fps.say.GFX" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>       

         <activity
            android:name=".GFXSurface"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fps.say.GFXSURFACE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>          


        <activity
            android:name=".OpenedClass"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fps.say.OPENEDCLASS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".SoundStuff"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fps.say.SOUNDSTUFF" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>        


        <activity
            android:name=".Slider"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fps.say.SLIDER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>          

        <activity
            android:name=".Tabs"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fps.say.TABS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>             

        <activity
            android:name=".SimpleBrowser"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fps.say.SIMPLEBROWSER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>     

        <activity
            android:name=".SharedPrefs"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fps.say.SHAREDPREFS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>         

        <activity
            android:name=".InternalData"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fps.say.INTERNALDATA" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>          

        <activity
            android:name=".ExternalData"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fps.say.EXTERNALDATA" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>          

        <activity
            android:name=".SQLView"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fps.say.SQLVIEW" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>         


        <activity
            android:name=".SQLiteExample"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.fps.say.SQLITEEXAMPLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>           




    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Would you mind posting your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possible ways to run an activity.
Here's the method I use:

```
Intent i = new Intent (this, YourTargetActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

The *this* corresponds to your current activity.

Using such a call gives you the convenience to have your IDE autocomplete the desired activity name.

Answer (score 0):

- Dubble check the name of the class
- Dubble check the name which should be mentioned in the manifest file
- Perform a clean-build

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,SQLVIEW.class);
```